# Getting different plot results from wolfram alpha and mathematica

Tags: plotting, functions

I'm trying to draw this function:
$$f(x) = x(\theta(x-1)-\theta(x-2))$$
Where $\theta(x)$ denotes the Heaviside theta function, in mathematica I wrote the function this way:

```
f[x_] = xHeavisideTheta[x - 1] - xHeavisideTheta[x - 2]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

But then this is the plot that I get in Mathematica:
[image: Mathematica]

Whereas in wolfram alpha I get this following plot:
[image: wolfram alpha]

What am I doing wrong in mathematica?

Comment: just add space after the `x` like this ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfJZH.png)   i.e. change `xHeavisideTheta[x - 1]` to `x *HeavisideTheta[x - 1]`

Comment: @Nasser Thank you I just had to add the * without the space to get it to work, I thought it would automatically multiply without the * like when I multiply a variable by a constant

Comment: Without either a space or an asterisk, `xHeavisideTheta` is a single symbol. Mathematica will not try to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to spaces, I also use := when I define a function,

this should work:

```
f[x_] := x HeavisideTheta[x - 1] - x HeavisideTheta[x - 2]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```